# ViewEncaptulation.None child does not get styles from parent Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am on the middle of refactor some Angular 4 code to Angular 7. So far so good.

I have this component `ConfigMenu` with this config

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-config-menu',
  templateUrl: './config-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config-menu.component.scss']
})
```

Since it had so many items that can be separated I did a child component `GeneralOptions`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-general-options',
  templateUrl: './general-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./general-options.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Side note: I know I will do them `On.Push` soon.

The problem I have is that the `CSS` from my parent component is not applied to my child component.

For example I have this:

```
.list {
   margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
   margin-top: 0;
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

That gets transformed to:

```
.list[_ngcontent-c1] {
    margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

but my `.list` item inside `app-general-options.html` does not get the `[_ngcontent-c1]` attribute so no styles are applied.

As I understand. If I set `ViewEncaptulation.None` it should get all the styles from above. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `I did a child component GeneralOption and it has a child component GeneralOptions` ? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding, ViewEncapsulation.None does not mean that your component is free to be penetrated by all the app, but the opposite: that your component penetrates the whole app.

If you add ViewEncap None to your parent component, it will do what you want.

If this creates conflict, a workaraound might be using ::ng-deep behind each class in the css

`::ng-deep .list {...}`

and it will penetrate encapsulation. Or simply contain your whole css of the parent in a

`::ng-deep:host{ .. your css .. }`

hope this helps

Comment: When you say my component penetrates all my app with `.None` that means if I have a something like `div { background: red}` in my component, all the `div`s inside my all will have a background red?

Comment: I answer myself: Yes it does.